# How to solve error "Cannot set property 'emulateTransitionEnd' of undefined" in Bootstrap node.js app?

Tags: jquery, node.js, twitter-bootstrap

I created Node.js application from scratch and I have added in app.js.

```
global.jQuery = require('jquery');
```

After that it gives me error as below:

```
/home/yojna/web/node_modules/bootstrap/js/transition.js:36
  $.fn.emulateTransitionEnd = function (duration) {
                        ^
    TypeError: Cannot set property 'emulateTransitionEnd' of undefined
    at /home/yojna/web/node_modules/bootstrap/js/transition.js:36:29
    at Object.<anonymous>(/home/yojna/web/node_modules/bootstrap/js/transition.js:59:2)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> 
    (/home/yojna/web/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/npm.js:2:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    yojna@yojna-Inspiron-7520:~/web$
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NPM is made to include server-side libraries.
To include client-side libraries such as bootstrap or jquery, you shoud use [Bower](http://bower.io/) instead.

I've done this in an expressjs app :

1. Create a .bowerrc file and write the following lines :

   ```
   {
     "directory" : "public/components"
   }
   ```
2. Download bootstrap and jquery with Bower :

   ```
   bower install bootstrap
   ```
3. Then, define your public folder to be static in your app.js file :

   ```
   app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
   ```
4. Finally, add the script tag in your view (I'am using Jade here) :

   ```
   script(src='components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js')
   script(src='components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js')
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Try declare dollar sign variable:

```
global.jQuery = global.$ = require('jquery');
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem, and it was because I had included "bootstrap" in my vendor webpack 2 config but was using:

```
require("bootstrap-loader");
```

So the browser couldn't properly find the bootstrap-loader package.

Comment: This helped. I incorrectly tried to include bootstrap in my app.module.ts typescript file by using `import 'bootstrap';` and should have included it in my webpack config.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't `require` it. Jquery is a client side library while Node.js is a backend server.

If you want to use Jquery with your Node.js app, simply add it to your HTML files with:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: You didn't answer the OPs question.